# Python OSError 54 ECONNRESET Germany

Tags: python

I have a question to a nasty general problem.

I live in Germany and every 24 hrs the internet providers cut the lines, so that we get a new IP.

I have a program running in Python and it stops working every night. Thats annoying. I am new to python and I am wondering if there's a "out of the box" solution to "bridge" over these 5 to seven minutes without internet connection.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does the program do?

Comment: @AKX It communicates with a stock market via API every minute.

Comment: You might just need to handle the socket/connection errors within the program and retry until it succeeds again, or have a cron job/scheduled task that automatically restarts the program at a certain time.